# Set Windows authentication timeout at runtime

Tags: asp.net, timeout, windows-authentication

Is there a way top specify the authentication timeout for an Asp.Net application using windows authentication?

In my scenario the user logged into Windows does not have permission to the web application so the browser prompts them for a different set of Active Directory credentials. Assuming they don't tick the "Remember my credentials" check box I'd like to be able to set how long the user will stay authenticated for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not be possible from ASP.NET configuration.

As such, windows authentication may use Kerberos or NTLM. AFAIK, NTLM is connection based and connection life-time decides authentication scope. For kerberos, a time-bound token is issued. The token time-out is generally small (say few minutes) and is dependent upon the setup.

Perhaps you should explain the the specific need to set the windows authentication time-out (because typically, time-outs are designed to avoid replay attacks and underlying windows authentication as such take care of them so there is hardly any need to do something at application level).

Comment: A customer has asked for the timeout on windows authenticated sessions to be configurable. One scenario is where they have workstations logged on with generic accounts but then to access the ASP.Net app users will need to logon with their specific Active Directory account. After a day researching I've come to the conclusion that the only option is a javascript hack that clears IE's credentials cache but that just introduces other problems so I think in such scenarios they should use Forms authentication.

Comment: @sipwiz, can generic accounts be authenticated at server end (i.e. does server recognize them as valid windows credentials)? If no then I believe that IE would prompt for credentials acceptable on the server.

Comment: Yes the generic accounts are valid AD accounts as well, that's the problem.

Comment: @sipwiz, try sending HTTP 401 response code from server if the authenticated user is from generic account (provided you have a mechanism to find out as such). I believe that browser will prompt fro credentials if credentials supplied were rejected.